# What is the chance that all three shooters will hit the target, given that probability that each one will target the aim is given.

Tags: probability

The probability that the first person will hit the target is $P(A)=0.7$, the probability that the second person will hit the target is $P(B)=0.6$ and the probability, that the third person will hit the target is given as $P(C)=0.8$. Is it as simple as $P(\text{all three shooters hit the target})=\frac{1}{2^3}$?

Comment: Why would you think that?  If all three events are independent, then the answer is the product $\frac 7{10}\times \frac 6{10}\times \frac 8{10}=\frac {42}{125}$

Comment: Language note:  I expect you intended the word "target" instead of "aim".

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the probability of each person hitting the "aim" is independent, then we can just multiply the probabilities together.

$P(A\cap B\cap C) = P(A)P(B)P(C)=(0.7)(0.6)(0.8)=0.336$

Further Reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)#More_than_two_events